# Giving specific options to user when creating tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I am making  a terrain analysis tool for military use (educational purposes). I am doing a raster analysis, using standardised terrain data in combination with a surface raster to determine the maneuverability in a user specified area.

My model gives a weighted raster output, which I will symbolise in a logical way if/when I get the results I want. Over time I will add more input (especially soil type) to the model, but this is the general design of it.
[image: Model Design]

I am struggling to find a way to let the user differentiate between wheeled and tracked vehicles, and dry and wet terrain. My assessment is that these two aspects will affect the result the most, but so far my solution has been to make several different tools with different weighting.

My best guess would be that I have to let the user choose between these options in the weighted overlay:

- Wheeled vehicles, dry soil
- Wheeled vehicles, wet soil
- Tracked vehicles, dry soil
- Tracked vehicles, wet soil

Is this possible in any way? Or any other workaround that removes the need for several tools?

Comment: I've not used Weighted Overlay tool but reading the help there is the influence parameter. I'm guessing you alter that on your soils layer as I assume tracked vehicles can move through all terrains whilst wheeled prefer roads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create a multivalue string variable as a Model Parameter.  This will allow the end user the ability to select a condition (Wheeled vehicles, dry soil, Wheeled vehicles, wet soil...etc)

In ModelBuilder:

1. Insert menu>Create Variable
2. Choose "String" and check the check box for Multivalue
3. Double click on variable graphic and add in pick values
4. Right click on variable and select Model Parameter option

Based on the value selected you could then use [If-Then-Else logic for branching](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//002w00000022000000) to apply the proper value into the Weighted Overlay tool.